# Performing and type-safe collection of value types in the early version of .NET

Tags: c#, performance, .net-1.1, value-type, c#-1.2

I recently got access to a very old C# code base (very old meaning .NET 1.1 and C# 1.2) in order to find places that could be improved. It is like a window to the past when a bow was the most powerfull weapon. I have never had the opportunity to willingly code in C# version lesser than C# 2 before.

Basically, what I have found is that there is a whole bunch of large `ArrayList`s for storing numbers and structs. By large I mean tens or hundreds of thousand of values. Something like

```
ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < BIG_CONSTANT; i++)
    numbers.Add(someNumberReturnedFromMethod);
```

These lists are sorted on some place then again sorted by a different standard on another place, or there are searches performed on them.

Knowing that `ArrayList` works with objects results in two problems I came up with

- no type-safety
- boxing and unboxing everywhere

So the question is, how to solve this without the aid of generics? I definitely will not make classes from these structs in order to remove un/boxing, because with so many data, this really makes difference (tested).

I thought about creating custom array lists that would work with my structs instead. Do I have to create a custom array list implementation for every struct there is? Thinging about it, it would mean to define my own IEnumerable, ICollection and IList for each of these structs, right?

I think that it could be a good cost to pay in order to get more performing and type-safe system, but before trying it out I would like to know your opinion.

Comment: You're struck with .net 1.1? When you plan to improve the project why not use atleaset .net2.0?

Comment: If your actual question is _"What can I replace my `ArrayList`s with in order to improve performance"_, I'm afraid the answer is _"Benchmark it"_. You obviously know about the alternatives, but whether any of them make any sense probably entirely depends on how they are being used in that project.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I wish it was that easy. It is not like I'm going to say to a customer - "Hey, I will install .NET 2.0 on your server to see if it works better and if not ...". They don't want to here that.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have an alternative, yes, but I would like to consult it here, first. Benchmarking is sure thing. I also thought that this could be an interesting question for SO folk.

Comment: Arrays don't lead to boxing, and they can be sorted. So your example could read: `NumberStruct[] numbers = new NumberStruct[BIG_CONSTANT]; for(int i = 0; i < BIG_CONSTANT; i++)
    numbers[i] = someNumberReturnedFromMethod;`. Clearly the problem is that arrays are fixed-sized, but I think you would use arrays a lot more if you didn't have access to (truly) generic types, such as `List<>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without generics you cannot create a collection that avoids boxing with value types. But you can create specialized collections for concrete value types.

Here's an idea: Create your own version of `ArrayList` but use **T4 templates** to generate specialized versions for every concrete type you care about. That gives you, without code duplication, an `ArrayListInt32`, an `ArrayListSingle` and so on.

This removes any performance penalty from the boxing and restores type safety.

Actually, Java has a similar problem because due to type erasure they cannot use generics to avoid boxing. They do have some specialized array list classes in newer versions. Thank god C# does implement true generics in recent versions.

Comment: I used T4 templates for structuring an email body, but I would have never thought about using it for this. Nice point indeed!